# Como excluir um caracter no Python

Tags: python, funções, data, data.frame

Estou iniciando estudo com análise de dados, só que ainda não sei como excluir caracteres

```
import re
import panda as pd 
df.rename (columns = ("nome_motorista***************": "nome_motorista"))
```

ou seja caractere `******` numa tabela de 40000 nomes

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você deva mudar só como esta passando os dados no parâmetro `columns`, pela documentação esse parâmetro recebe um `dict-like`. Só precisa fazer a troca dos parenteses `()` por chaves `{}`.

A chamada correta para função `rename` seria:

`df.rename(columns = {"nome_motorista***************": "nome_motorista"})`

PS: estou imaginando que você está fazendo as chamadas de leitura corretamente, já que não colocou essa parte no código, caso esse trecho seja seu código completo, tem mais coisa que precisa ser feito antes.

Vide documentação do [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)